# Qualifying a column in a SQL select statement

Tags: sql

I'm looking to generate a query that pulls from several tables. Most are rather straightforward and I can pull a value from a table directly but there is one table that is pivoted so that the value I want depends on the value in another column.

The table looks like the below:

```
ID   Condition   Value
1     Stage1      6
2     Stage2      9
3     Stage3      5
4     Stage4      2
```

So I'm looking to write a query that essentially "qualifies" the value I want by telling the table which condition.

An example of my SQL:

```
Select Attribute1, Stage1Value, Stage2Value, Stage3Value
From attribute, stage
where attribute = project1
```

So I can't just pull the "Value" column as it needs to know which stage in the query.

There are 30 columns I am trying to pull - of which 13 fall into this category. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What you are looking to do is most commonly called "Pivoting". Tag your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, etc...). Do a search on "Pivoting table in <insert your DBMS> and you'll find everything you need. Also, you should break the habit of using the old join syntax. Refer to Yogesh's answer for the better way to write joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want *conditional* aggregation something :

```
select a.<col>, 
       sum(case when s.Condition = 'Stage1' then s.value else 0 end),
       . . .
       sum(case when s.Condition = 'Stage4' then s.value else 0 end)
from attribute a inner join 
     stage s
     on s.<col> = a.<col>
group by a.<col>
```